# C# Graphic Fill Tool

Tags: c#, graphics

Hello i have a small problem whit graphic.

I have a list of image whit size 32x32

i need to detect if in this image have a colored pixel or is empty.

for example:

my image
[          .              ]

The dot are a pixel inside the image.
i have used this code but does work

```
 bool tile_preset = false;

                            for(int b = 0; b < temp.Height;b++)
                            {
                                for(int a = 0; a < temp.Width; a++)
                                {
                                    Color c = temp.GetPixel(a, b);
                                    tile_preset = (c.A != 0 && c.R != 0 && c.G != 0 && c.B != 0) ? true : false;
if (tile_present)
break;


                                }
                            }
```

in all case, i have False

else i use a full colored image i have true

Comment: This code only returns true if the last pixel meets the conditions.

Comment: I guess you have to modify the code to this:-  (c.R != 0 || c.G != 0 || c.B != 0) I don't think you need to check alpha as a color pixel.

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz i have corrected whit a break statement but nothing

Comment: @JoeMartiniello check with a full white pixel and then read my answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is "wrong" in several ways. First of all, is it true that all the "non-colored" pixels in the image are `ARGB(0,0,0,0)`?

If so, a colored pixel is found if *any* of the color values is not 0! Your code checks whether *all* of them are not 0, so a full-red pixel would not be counted!

Also, the expression you have is already a boolean. Why use the ternary operator to convert a boolean into a boolean?

And third: You *must* exit the loop as soon as you found a pixel that is not neutral.

```
bool tile_preset = false;

for(int b = 0; b < temp.Height && !tile_preset; b++)
{
    for(int a = 0; a < temp.Width && !tile_preset; a++)
    {
        Color c = temp.GetPixel(a, b);
        tile_preset = (c.A != 0 || c.R != 0 || c.G != 0 || c.B != 0);
    }
}
```

Alternatively need to make sure `tile_preset` is modified only if you found a pixel.

```
bool tile_preset = false;

for(int b = 0; b < temp.Height; b++)
{
    for(int a = 0; a < temp.Width; a++)
    {
        Color c = temp.GetPixel(a, b);
        tile_preset |= (c.A != 0 || c.R != 0 || c.G != 0 || c.B != 0);
    }
}
```

This causes `tile_preset` to change from `false` to `true` when you found a colored pixel, but never change back to `false` when the next pixels is again neutral.

Comment: Do we have to check alpha value as well?

Comment: It really depends on whether you consider `ARGB(67,0,0,0)` a colored pixel or not :-) It is **your** definition, so: If the alpha value is relevant in your scenario, check it. If you only need the red, green and blue values, then don't.